# Java / Netbeans cannot find the library / package

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I am getting started with this new hardware similar to arduino, called tinkerforge. To actually control any of it (parts havn't arrived yet) in Java you need to include the library within your project.

I create a new library and added the class path, netbeans finds all the files perfectly fine and shows them. (Screenshot) yet it still cannot find any of the classes or the library itself when I use import.

I spent 4 hours trying to figure out whats wrong and have gotten nowhere. I don't usually come to have my problems solved :/ I'm new to java though so I might be missing something?

ps. when I run it i get the java error saying the packages arn't found.

Link to a bigger image: [Netbeans Image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19465259/netbeans-tingerforge.jpg)

[image: Netbeans]

Comment: Did you try restarting NetBeans?

Comment: And also try creating a new project and adding this library and doing a import statement.

Comment: Yes tried both of those things, none of them work. I have no clue why this isn't working. If I type com. it only shows up oracle & sun, although if I import a different library it shows up in the com. selection menu.

Comment: it could well be multiple jar versions with the same class names in the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you used http://download.tinkerforge.com/bindings/java/tinkerforge_java_bindings_latest.zip which seems to be corrupt. If I add this lib to a project, manually use a FQN:

```
    com.tinkerforge.BrickletTemperature t = null;
```

and build with Ant, it produces an error:

```
.../src/....java:4: error: cannot access BrickletTemperature
        com.tinkerforge.BrickletTemperature t = null;
  bad class file: /tmp/Tinkerforge.jar(com/tinkerforge/BrickletTemperature.class)
    class file contains wrong class: bindings.BrickletTemperature
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
1 error
```

`javap` confirms that the classes are not in the declared package. Report to the manufacturer.